# how to remove autofocus in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using `angular 6` with `angular material design`.I make simple application of `slidebar` with `toggle menu` icon. I am facing one issue .whenever I am selection any item from `slidebar menu` currently I have `3` items select any item .It close my slide bar navigation , but my `menu button` is auto focus .

here is my code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-353qur?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontactmanager%2Fcomponents%2Ftoolbar%2Ftoolbar.component.html

[image]

**Steps to reproduce this bug**

1. Select menu button or icon .it shows sidebar having three option.
2. Select any option it close sidebar and `menu` icon is auto focus .why ??

I want to remove auto focus after selection of item from sidebar

**Update**

Please check on `mobile` .click on `F12` and selection mobile.
please check on small device

**const SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT = 560;**

**Important point**

you will only reproduce this bug when you output window in less than 500px

Comment: Unable to reproduce this bug, sidebar doesn't close after selecting one of three items.

Comment: wait checking again

Comment: @CommercialSuicide it is doning .Please don't click on same item

Comment: I cant see auto focus now.Is this fixed?

Comment: no it is not fixed

Comment: @bews99 please follow the steps and see the above image

Comment: yes. I followed https://ibb.co/fd8tny

Comment: can you check this on a native browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173285/discussion-between-user944513-and-bews99).

Comment: I think you didn't get my mistake sorry .Please check on mobile version

Comment: updating my Question

Comment: I updated my question please check .pls check only below screen size 500px to reproduce bug.  const SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT = 560;

Comment: reduce the window size upto 500px
issue is the your output window more than 500px

Comment: @all please check my updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to remove css hover effect. add a class to the mat-button ('no-hover')

```
<button mat-button (click)="toggleSidenav.emit()" class="sidenav-toggle no-hover">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
</button>
```

and inside template css

```
.mat-button.no-hover ::ng-deep .mat-button-focus-overlay {
  background: none;
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to find this solution
i found this class .mat-button
as well as .mat-button-focus-overlay
where is ::ng-deep ?

Comment: 'Shadow Piercing combinators', it came from Angular 4.3.0. Here is a good blog post about that https://hackernoon.com/the-new-angular-ng-deep-and-the-shadow-piercing-combinators-deep-and-drop-4b088dbe459

Comment: and this https://alligator.io/angular/styles-between-components-angular/

Comment: is this issue resolved, I m facing same, and given solution is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

add the below style in styles.css

```css
// remove blue border focus
button:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```